# Creating a error component in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm fairly new to Angular and I am stuck.

I have a form which when a user doesn't fill the required fields gives an error on submit. Instead of giving an error on the page (like the attachment), I want this error to show up on a modal.

Like when a user doesn't fill the required fields and hit submits, a modal appears giving us the error telling us what went wrong.

How would I create an error modal? I want to create a new component for this error because I want to be able to use this component on various pages.

```
onSubmit() {
  //do something 
  }, err => {
     //How would I make my error component open when there is an error here.
     console.log("err");
  }
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpvMh.png)

Comment: Just an opinion ... from a user's perspective displaying the errors in a modal is not very user friendly. If there are several errors, the user has to memorize the list and then close the modal to fix each one. Seems like it would be friendlier to build an error component that you could add to any page to display errors. Or just add the errors next to the fields.

Comment: I like the idea of creating an error component but how do I make sure that the component shows up when there's an error? I created a component called error-modal. What should I do on my onSubmit() to make sure that when there is an error, the component shows up? 
I hope I make sense. And Thanks!!

Comment: I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't paste a screen shot into my comment, so here is a picture of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Both Angular template-driven and Angular reactive forms are set up to display error messages such as these.

To actually answer your question ... there is an example of creating a model here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Or you can use material design's modal here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

In the template:

```
<my-error-component *ngIf="isError"></my-error-component>
```

In the component:

```
isError: boolean

onSubmit() {
  //do something 
  }, err => {
     isError = true;
     console.log("err");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using named router-outlets, you can create a bootstrap modal fairly easily:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    template: `
    <div class="modal fade in show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
    `
})

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [{ path: 'open',  component: ModalComponent, outlet: 'modal'}]
    )
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ModalComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  exports: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

To trigger the modal, create a link:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { modal:'open' }}]">Click Me</a>
```

Or inject router and navigate to 'open':

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
}

openDialog() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { modal:'open' }}]);
}
```

To close the dialog:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { modal:null }}]">Click Me</a>
```

Or

```
closeDialog() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { modal: null }}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show any error on **onSubmit** then you can use material design dialog which is best compatible with angular2.

**below is the link for the code and running example that how you can open dialog**
[Click here for demo code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdngyqykpnl)

**below is the link for official doc of Modal in material design**

[Check official doc for dialog in Angular2](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Hope this will help you :)